# Why is this SQL query syntax incorrect?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve some video information from a MySQL database and searching for it via a `$_GET["v"]` request and a mysql query "seen below":

```
$video = $_GET['v'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM vid--data WHERE v = '".htmlspecialchars($video)."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '--data WHERE v = '5JxC0plA3kz'' at line 1
```

How is this error possible?

Comment: wrap `vid--data` inside ``

Comment: Space not allowed in table name as vid--data

Comment: Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: why you don't use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: If `--` was not allowed, how would he be able to create the table? Maybe put the tablename in backticks.

Comment: Side note: the legacy mysql extension has been discouraged for several years and was finally removed from PHP some weeks ago.

Comment: your query translates to `vid` MINUS MINUS `data`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, PHP and SQL are entirely different languages. This question is completely unrelated to PHP to begin with.

As about SQL syntax, the [Language Structure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/language-structure.html) chapter offers a complete overview but you're specifically violating what's explained at [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html):

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever
>   you refer to it.

... and:

> ```
>  Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
>     ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>
>     Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> ```

... thus `-` is not allowed in an *unquoted* identifier. Just quote it:

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```

(Maybe next time you could use more practical names when naming stuff so don't need to quote them every time.)